# Data assignment without copying to cv::Mat and cv::UMat from other OpenCV Matrix

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm stuck with the data assignment without copying in C++ OpenCV (version 3.4.1).

Please have a look at the following example code:

```
std::cout << "test cv::Mat" << std::endl;
cv::Mat a(2, 2, CV_32FC1, cv::Scalar(1.));
cv::Mat b(2, 2, CV_32FC1, cv::Scalar(5.));
std::cout << "a:" << std::endl << a << std::endl;
std::cout << "b:" << std::endl << b << std::endl;

a.col(0) = b.col(0);
std::cout << "a:" << std::endl << a << std::endl;
std::cout << "b:" << std::endl << b << std::endl;

a.col(0) = b.row(0).t();
std::cout << "a:" << std::endl << a << std::endl;
std::cout << "b:" << std::endl << b << std::endl;

std::cout << "test cv::UMat" << std::endl;
cv::UMat c(2, 2, CV_32FC1, cv::Scalar(1.));
cv::UMat d(2, 2, CV_32FC1, cv::Scalar(5.));
std::cout << "c:" << std::endl << c << std::endl;
std::cout << "d:" << std::endl << d << std::endl;

c.col(0) = d.col(0);
std::cout << "c:" << std::endl << c << std::endl;
std::cout << "d:" << std::endl << d << std::endl;

c.col(0) = d.row(0).t();
std::cout << "c:" << std::endl << c << std::endl;
std::cout << "d:" << std::endl << d << std::endl;
```

This gives the following output:

```
test cv::Mat
a:
[1, 1;
1, 1]
b:
[5, 5;
5, 5]
a:
[1, 1;
1, 1]
b:
[5, 5;
5, 5]
a:
[5, 1;
5, 1]
b:
[5, 5;
5, 5]
test cv::UMat
[ INFO:0] Initialize OpenCL runtime...
c:
[1, 1;
1, 1]
d:
[5, 5;
5, 5]
c:
[1, 1;
1, 1]
d:
[5, 5;
5, 5]
c:
[1, 1;
1, 1]
d:
[5, 5;
5, 5]
```

In case of cv::Mat, why is the assigment with `a.col(0) = b.col(0);` **not working**?

Why is the assigment with `a.col(0) = b.row(0).t();` **working**?

Why is it different in case of cv::UMat?

The goal behind all this is to concatenate a cv::Mat (or better cv::UMat) from multiple other OpenCV matrices, **without copying** the data (which might be expensive due to the amount of data).

Is this possible at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it's not possible to concatenate multiple OpenCV matrices into a single one without copying of data.

The class `cv::Mat` holds only single pointer to data, that does not allow handling multiple memory regions.

There are also pointers `datastart`, `dataend` and `datalimit` in `cv::Mat`, but these are just helpers for support of a region of interest. They help handling smaller matrices without data copying, not larger.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `a.row()` or `a.col()`, the data in `a` is not copied
to the new array. Like `d = b.col(0);`: This expression
means to create a new array header `d` , and to arrange its data pointer, step array, and so on, such that it will access the data in col 0 in `d`.
So that's why it does look like it doesn't work and when you add transpose `.t()` to it then you're not in the same case.

For CPU version, in `.t()` you are not applying the same rule as `.col()` but simply assigning a vector to another matrix, hence its value has been copied/modified.

For `UMat`, I don't have enough information what exactly using GPU or CPU to perform the task. For me it is using my GPU but for you it doesn't seem to be:

```
test cv::UMat
[ INFO:0] Initialize OpenCL runtime...
[ INFO:0] Successfully initialized OpenCL cache directory: /home/jdros/.cache/opencv/3.4.1-dev/opencl_cache/
[ INFO:0] Preparing OpenCL cache configuration for context: NVIDIA_Corporation--GeForce_930MX--384_81
```

**Recommendations:**
With newer versions of `OpenCV`, you get more optimized code and more faster. So I would recommend you to read about each particular function about copying data in memory and/or try some code yourself where you can use those functions like `.clone()`, `copyTo()`..etc. For example, a simple assignment is not the best way of matrix copying, which is what you really need, however `.clone()` is literally copying data in memory.. But investigate that with every function you're using, it worth it.

I found some more informations in a book called: `Learning OpenCV 3: Computer Vision in C++ with the OpenCV Library`:

It is critical to understand that the data in an array is not attached rigidly to the array object. The `cv::Mat` object is really a header for a data area, which—in principle—is an entirely separate thing. For example, it is possible to assign one matrix `n` to another matrix `m` (i.e., `m=n` ). In this case, the data pointer inside of `m` will be changed to point to the same data as `n` . The data pointed to previously by the data element of `m` (if any) will be deallocated (Technically, it will only be deallocated if m was the last `cv::Mat` that pointed to that particular data). At the same time, the reference counter for the data area that they both now share will be incremented. Last but not least, the members of `m` that characterize its data (such as `rows` , `cols` , and `flags` ) will be updated to
accurately describe the data now pointed to by data in `m` . This all results in a very convenient behavior, in which arrays can be assigned to one another, and the work necessary to do this takes place automatically behind the scenes to give the correct result.

Comment: Ok, but if the header of `a` is changed, why do I not see the data from `b` afterwards? Furthermore, transpose `.t()` should also not copy the data, should it? Why do I see a change there?

Finally, why is the behavior different for `UMat`?

Comment: @gondo I added some more information. I'm not familiar with `UMat` opencl version

Comment: Ok, I think, I understand. In our case, OpenCL uses the CPU (in lack of a GPU on the server), which makes the difference hard to grasp.

My last question was, if it is possible to concatenate a cv::Mat (or better cv::UMat) from multiple other OpenCV matrices, **without copying the data** (which might be expensive due to the amount of data). Do you have advice regarding this?

Basically, my concatenated matrix header should point to different memory locations, e.g. for each column.

Comment: @gondo I added some recommendations